# Apache reverse proxy blocks requests with SQL in request body

Tags: windows, apache-http-server

I'm using Apache httpd 2.2.15 on Windows 2008 as a reverse proxy in front of some web applications.  While using the application, if the user enters the following text, the HTTP connection is closed without a response, and the request is not actually forwarded to the backend application.  There's no evidence of the request in the Apache access or error logs either.

```
INSERT INTO business_parameter bp
SELECT * 
FROM business fund
```

Note that if the user takes the "bp" out of the text and uses the following, this problem does not occur:

```
INSERT INTO business_parameter
SELECT * 
FROM business fund
```

Also, if the user connects their browser directly to the backend application (bypassing the reverse proxy), the problem does not occur.

Below is the configuration for the virtual server with the reverse proxy:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot "D:/Apache2.2/htdocs-qvjira101"
    ServerName qvjira101.office.qvalent.com
    ServerAlias qvjira101
    ErrorLog logs/qvjira101-error.log
    CustomLog "|D:/Apache2.2/bin/rotatelogs.exe D:/Apache2.2/logs/qvjira101-access.log 86400" common

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass           /       http://localhost:9080/
    ProxyPassReverse    /       http://localhost:9080/

    <Directory "D:/Apache2.2/htdocs-qvjira101">
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

This problem occurs across several backend web applications from different vendors.  The fact that it doesn't occur when bypassing the Apache reverse proxy leads me to believe that it's a problem with Apache.  Any ideas?